# Button BackgroundColor disables the LinearLayout BackgroundColor

Tags: android

What can I do so that the `android:background` color of the Button doesn’t disable the LinearLayout `android:background` color? It’s when creating Buttons dynamically.
Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);

        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));  // WHITE
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText(myList.get(i));

        myButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.naranja)); // ORANGE

        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
        myButton.setId(i);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { ………
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not disabling the background color, you're drawing on top of it. If you change the LayoutParams to WRAP_CONTENT for width, you'll notice the background color is still white. Also, if you add some padding around the button you'll notice the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it works changing WRAP_CONTENT for width, but this is not what I like. I think that using padding would solve the problem. However, any parameters I write in this instruction don’t change anything: the Button background color disables the background color: 
myButton.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0); // OR ANY OTHERS

Comment: Try adding margin and not padding.

Comment: Sorry, I have found the problem. I had to setMargins to LayoutParams, then setLayoutParams to my view, like this:
params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
myButton.setLayoutParams(params);